# Creating the new allure adapter for own framework

Tags: ant, allure

I'm trying to create the adapter for our own framework. Our framework uses its own assert mechanism so I need to write the adapter.

The adapter class is very simple and it looks like this:

```
public class AllureReportListener {

    private static AllureReportListener object = new AllureReportListener();

    private Allure lifecycle = Allure.LIFECYCLE;

    private String suiteUid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    private Set<String> startedTestNames = Collections.newSetFromMap(
            new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Boolean>());

    public static AllureReportListener getReportListener()
    {
        return object;
    }

    public void onTestSuiteStart(String testCaseName)
    {
        getLifecycle().fire(new TestSuiteStartedEvent(
                suiteUid,testCaseName
        ));
    }

    public void onTestSuiteFinish()
    {
        getLifecycle().fire(new TestSuiteFinishedEvent(suiteUid));
    }

    Allure getLifecycle() {
        return lifecycle;
    }
}
```

Our own test suite class calls these methods on right event times.

Since we have our own testing framework, we have our own `ant` task called `ownrunner` like this:

```
<target name="test">
    <ownrunner classpathref="classpath" file="config/usecase/SEEDLoginCase.xml" parallel="Scenario" output="${build.report}">
    </ownrunner>
</target>
```

I ran the ant build, but I didn't see any allure results in the build folder.

Now I'm struck. I want this ant task generates the allure xml results. What I need to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to start the aspect jar too, part of the ant build. Add this line to your build:

```
<jvmarg value="-javaagent:${currentDir}/aspectjweaver-1.8.0.jar"/>
```

This will help you to get the allure results, under the directory you have configured.